# Trying to count rows when creating excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a GridView that I am converting to an Excel Spreadsheet. I want the first column to count the rows i.e. if there are 10 rows in the spreadsheet then the first column should display 1 to 10. But right now the spreadsheet is just displaying the last number for all columns. So if the excel has 10 rows, the number 10 is there for each row instead of counting up from one.

```
int Sno = 1;
for (Sno = 1; Sno < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; Sno++)
{
       Sno++;
}

downloadcsv.WriteLine("\"" + Sno + "\",\"" +                            
                    dr["CustomerName"].ToString() + "\",\"" +
                    dr["invoiceno"].ToString() + "\","
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a loop that counts each row, but you aren't setting any values inside the loop. You only set a single value after the loop. So of course you are only setting the number for the last row.

You will need to set the data for each row, inside of your loop body.

Sorry, I'd sketch out the code for you but I can't really tell what `downloadcsv` is or why on Earth you'd be using `WriteLine()` like that.

Comment: downloadcvs is just creating the excel file `downloadcsv = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create));`. I'm not sure how to set the data for each row.

Comment: He's saying to just look at your loop, yes you are counting each row, but replacing the number each time the loop runs, so by the time you write anything you only have the last number

Comment: @Scriven yes I understand now but I still don't know how to set the data for each row. Could you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

simple add the "serial no"  in gridview column itself without using any counter,

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S#" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

if not showing to user then use

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S#" Visible="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```